# Send Variable to PHP using Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DMBS that I want to connect on my android application.
I've written the PHP for the connection and implemented on the app, I'm able to read correctly the data but I don't know how to send a variable via POST or GET to my PHP and I need to because I want to do a search query with the value of the variable.
Here's my main codes:

**ON ANDROID**

```
private void getData()
{
    try
    {
        URL url=new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.getOutputStream().write(postDataByte);
        is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Parse JSON data
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jo=null;

        data=new String[ja.length()];
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
            data[i]=jo.getString("Link");
            URL=data[i];
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

**ON PHP**

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$server_username="root";
$server_password="";
$dbName="anime";

//$nome=$_POST['Nome'];

//Make connection
$conn=new mysqli($servername, $server_username, $server_password, $dbName);
//Check connection
if(!$conn)
    die("Connection failed.".mysqli_connect_error());
$sql="SELECT links.Link
      FROM anime, episodi, links
      WHERE anime.Anime_ID=episodi.ID_Anime
      AND   episodi.ID_Episodio=links.Episodio_ID
      AND   anime.Nome='Sakura Quest'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    //Show data for each row
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $flag[]=$row;
        //echo "Titolo: ".$row['Titolo']." Link: ".$row['Link'].";";
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The android application automatically close if the "$nome=$_POST['Nome'];" is uncommented, i think it's because on the app it's sending a null Uri.
Here's a voice from my log of the application

```
11-14 15:30:03.412 32044-32044/com.example.mr50a.videoplayer W/System.err: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object 
reference
```

I really hope you guys can help me.

Comment: `but i don't know how to send a variable via POST or GET to my PHP ` That is a pretty standard action. You can find plenty examples on the internet and onstackoverflow.

Comment: I tried to do that, i tried with con.getOutputStream().write(postData); but didn't find out. On the web i searched a lot, for many days but i'm still stucked.

Comment: `con.getOutputStream().write(postDataByte);`. Do you really think we know what you are posting there?

Comment: I'm posting a string that i've parsed as byte, tried using the bufferedwriter on the OutpuStream but nothing happens.

Comment: You have not done enough research. You are struggling with some basic concept

Comment: I'm doing my researches, and i'll keep doing 'till i find a solution to my problem. If you can help me i'll be graceful but like this you're not helping me. I'm not asking to do the code for me, i'm just asking how to send a variable to my PHP.

Comment: Did you try [any tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm) from the internet? What's the `address` of your PHP server?

Comment: `I'm posting a string that i've parsed as byte, `. Of course you do. We can see that. But what is it that you are posting? Do you really think we know that?

Comment: `but like this you're not helping me. I'm not asking to do the code for me, i'm just asking how to send a variable to my PHP. `Blame yourself. Until now you did not show us one variable. Or its value. And i already asked you twice what it was that you are posting.

Comment: In that string there should be a name, in base of that name i'm doing a research in the database by PHP. May Only problem is that i don't know how to correctly send that name to my PHP.

Comment: My god... Adapt your code so we can see how you put all those variables in it! Do i have to ask that yet again? Show us what you do!

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object 
reference`. What does this have to do with you trying to POST something? Nothing!

Comment: I've managed to send data via POST request to my PHP using a PrintStream. Thanks to the ones that gave me an helpful answer.